# IV-RE xtoverid testing both IV validity and RE vs FE?

Tags: regression, panel-data, instrumental-variables, hausman

I am running an `xtivreg, re` and an `xtoverid` afterwards.
My understanding of the help file and what I found online is that `xtoverid` basically compares IV-RE with FE (augmented RE). 
The test statistic I get is tiny and therefore p-value massive (0.8 to 0.9).

My plan was to first test for endogeneity and then afterwards test either the RE-IV or RE versus the respective FE or FE-IV. However, the test seems to combine this into one. So does that imply that both the instruments are valid **as well as** that RE preferable to FE? I find that hard to believe because the FE results differ massively.

Comment: well, there is the first formatting error. First line of what I wrote is missing. "Hi, thanks for taking the time and" sorry

Comment: might also be relevant to know that if I do not use instruments, the hausman test clear prefers the FE model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `xtoverid` is a test of overidentifying restrictions. When you apply this after `xtivreg` this is a test for whether your instruments are valid. It does not at the same time whether you should use fixed or random effects but you can use this test also for this purpose but separately. This is because testing fixed versus random effects is similar to testing orthogonality conditions as in the instrumental variables case.

For your problem what you optimally would do is:

1. compare fixed and random effects using the Hausman test
2. for this example say you choose fixed effects; if you are in doubt about endogeneity you can again use the Hausman test to compare fixed effects versus fixed effects with instrumental variables (the instrumental variables regression is consistent whether or not you have an endogeneity problem whilst the usual fixed effects regression is only consistent under exogeneity); use `xtoverid` afterwards to check whether your instruments are valid
3. if they are valid you are done; if they are not valid you need to find a better instrument and then compare fixed effects versus fixed effects with the new instrument. Perhaps you were just rejecting normal fixed effects in step 2 because your first instrument was bad

Here is some code for you to try out:

```
webuse nlswork
tsset idcode year

// the standard Hausman test (assumes homoscedasticity of the residuals)
xtreg ln_wage tenure age, fe
est store fe

xtreg ln_wage tenure age, re
est store re

hausman fe re, sigmaless

// the test rejects the null that differences in FE and RE are not systematic, so you should use FE

// the xtoverid command is also a Hausman test which you can use without assuming homoscedasticity, e.g. if you want to correct for autocorrelation by clustering on the id variable
xtreg ln_wage tenure age, re cluster(idcode)
xtoverid

// now run the IV fixed effects regression
xtivreg ln_wage age (tenure = south union), fe i(idcode)

// check whether the instruments are valid according to the test
xtoverid

// compare the results with fixed effects; Hausman rejects that the difference between IV fixed effects and fixed effects is not systematic so it's better to use IV (assuming that your instruments are valid)
est store ivfe
hausman ivfe fe
```

Comment: thanks a lot for that great answer, I will work through that!

Comment: If this was helpful to you, you may consider to accept this answer for your question. You can do so by ticking the check mark underneath the voting buttons :) If you have any further questions about this please feel free to ask.

Comment: I worked through your example and then tried it on my own data. When I do the FE-IV I get the error message: equation exactly identified. Well, I have two instruments as in your example so I should not get that message. Any idea what is going on? I tried it with and without controls same story.

Comment: nevermind, obviously it does not work. One of my instruments is at the higher level and therefore drops out.

Comment: @Andy Could you please let me know who to deal with autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity issues while there is a large N, small T panel data? Really, I used xtreg with vce (robust) option but again I checked for autocorrelation. There is still problematic.Thanks